# How to configure KDE Konsole to open new shells on a different machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, kde, konsole

How to configure the KDE Konsole that when I press on a "new tab" button, the new shell would open on another machine (thorugh ssh), and not on the current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- configure SSH login without password
- configure that the default shell that konsole uses is not `bash`, but `bash -c "/usr/bin/ssh user@other.machine"`